# Diagnosing WP-Cron jobs locking up my server

Tags: wp-cron, troubleshooting

I have two self-hosted WordPress servers load balanced and running the same three sites on both servers. For a while now, we have an issue where we either get unexpected CPU spikes causing one or both of the servers to lock up and freeze for a couple minutes, or a sudden drop and then spike in network traffic also causing the servers to freeze up.

Every time I have tried investigating the issue, the only clue I find is calls to wp-cron.php around the same time the issue occurs. I have no idea if this is actually the cause though.

How can I get more details on what jobs are being run by WP-Cron and also how long each one took to run, and any relevant logs I can look through? I'm desperately trying to fix this recurring issue and feel pretty lost right now.

Comment: Have you disabled wp cron and set up your own cron job on the servers?
`define( 'DISABLE_WP_CRON', true );`
then via crontab setup something like this:

`*/2 * * * * /path/to/wp-cli cron event run --due-now --path=/path/to/wordpress/`

Comment: @tdj I had no idea this is an option....what would be the benefit of doing it that way versus HTTP calls to itself? Also, would that command run all scheduled jobs? I'll do some more reading on it, thanks

Comment: The benefit is that events that are due to run don't stack up until someone visits the site. Otherwise, there could be lots of things that haven't been done in a while which are triggered at once, hence the sudden spike in server load. With this method, anything that is due to run will do so when the cronjob runs (that's the `--due-now` flag).

Comment: @tdj sounds like a good idea regardless, but unfortunately I don't think this is the issue since I have constant health checks going on all three sites. Do you think the fact that both servers run the cron jobs is an issue?

Comment: To debug if your problem does indeed have to do with a scheduled cron event, you could run two ssh sessions, one with `top` to see server load/cpu/memory/etc usage. In the other, you can run every event from `wp cron event list` separately to see what the culprit is (for example `wp cron event run wp_version_check`, it will also tell you how long it took to execute the cron event)